# Why it is not possible to use "type A = Promise<any>" as a return type for an async function?

Tags: typescript

```
async function AsyncFunction(): Promise<number> {
  return 0;
}
```

Works without without problem as expected;

---

```
async function AsyncFunction(): AsyncFunctionReturnType {
  return 0;
}

type AsyncFunctionReturnType = Promise<number>
```

Throws `"Type 'AsyncFunctionReturnType' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value. ts(1055)"`

---

**They look identical to me, why syntax matters here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include 'es2015' in your lib for 'ES5' or 'ES3' targets. There is no difference in the syntax - but rather the target that you compiled to: [Playground with error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=1&ssl=2&ssc=10&pln=2&pc=52#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwILmgMSSjUwAoBKALhgAUAndAW1RAFMAeCBRgI1boB8MAN4BYAFAwYdVsgR0sABgDcEgL4SJyMAAdWOPFEIoMEAEqz5EACq79AXloNmbTtz6CJQA) vs [ES2015 target](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=2#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwILmgMSSjUwAoBKALhzykJQwgCUBTZBAJwgBUwAHFjADeAWABQMGBzacsABgDc4gL7jxyfoNyQ6REsxldeAmAF4YABQ7oAtqhAsAPBAQ2ARiw4A+cUA)